# Why android allow Invisible view to have OnClick?

Tags: android, android-view

For example, if we set OnClick on button and also set it invisible
It still works right ? 
If yes, What's a real life scenario in which it would be beneficial ? 
If there is no use , Why does android even allow to have onClick on Invisible view and it doesn't even give warning or anything.

I am curious to know :')

Comment: Scenario: Guess where the apple is on screen and earn points! Don't want onClick on view that you can't see? Use `GONE`

Comment: when you are developing games, you may want to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Invisible objects still clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140625/android-invisible-objects-still-clickable)

Comment: @JyotiJK that's exactly what i thought like hidden bricks to power up in mario  

But i want to know how it can be helpful in apps and not games :')

Comment: certainly not a duplicate. However also not great question, since only the framework designers can answer this, and it's unlikely they will

Comment: A game is an app, isn't it? Do you Android to keep two separate personalized SDK for games and apps? This question is becoming silly.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 yes of course Game is an App i want to know for what else we can make use of Such invisible onClick views :)

Comment: That would come with scenarios when you actually work on an app (or game). Wait and you will see its benefits.

Comment: @TimCastelijns check my answer

Comment: @Lucem ok. I downvoted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because for a View `visibility` and `onClick` are completely independent properties.

When a View is `INVISIBLE` as per its property it is just not shown but present in the given place, so `onClick()` would work on the view.
In case if a view is `GONE`, as the view itself is not present at the expected place, `onClick` function wont be called.

Answer (score 1):

You are using android views in the wrong way.
Views have three properties to alter visibility which are

1. **Visible**: By default, all views are visible
2. **Invisible**: The `view` is not visible but occupies space and resources
3. **Gone**: The `view` is entirely out of the layout

`Visisble` is used to set a `view` from either of the other two.

`Invisible` is used when you want a certain `button` that is lying on top of another `view` to be clicked rather than the view. It can also be used when you want a `view` to occupy space but not be present for the user. This scenario might occur when using `LinearLayouts` with `android:layoutWeight`

`Gone` is used when you want to completely hide a view from the picture. This is common with login screens and welcome previews in apps

Comment: instead of downvoting, please comment the wrong issue of this answer