# How to check invisible checkbox in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-checkbox

I have created a **checkbox** with text and set as **invisible**. Currently it is **unchecked** and I know the position of the checkbox as I have boxes above. I want the box to be checked and visible when I tap at the position ( invisible at the moment ).

I am not sure if this is possible or not as I could not find anything after hours of Googling.Sharing the codes below.

### xml code

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_diabetes"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_regular"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="@string/diabetes"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorAsh"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_diabetes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I am try to make it visible programmatically. However it is not getting visible when I tap on the place where it is rendered.

```
       case R.id.check_diabetes:
            if (b == true) {
                tv_diabetes.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorBlue));
                check_diabetes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                diabetes = "1";
            } else {...
```

Comment: If you just need to check the checkbox programmatically, you can use ```CheckBox.setChecked(true)```.

Comment: @upgye1wi I Need the checkbox as checked and visible when someone taps there. I tried and it doesn't changes anything !

Comment: Then you can set onClickListener to the checkbox and it must do the trick. Making a view invisible doesn't disable its listener. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140625/android-invisible-objects-still-clickable

Comment: In xml replace your `CheckBox` `invisible` to `gone`

Comment: @Dinesh This seems to be working with onClickListener and setting to gone.

Comment: @vinuraj_pg or you can set alpha property to 0 and then back to 1. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding an onClickListener like this:

```
 check_diabetes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check_diabetes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            check_diabetes.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky way to get what you want. In your layout file, set `android:alpha="0"`, but set `android:visibility="true"` all the time.
And then in code

```
final CheckBox checkDiabetes= new CheckBox(R.id.check_diabetes);
            checkDiabetes.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked)
                checkBox.setAlpha(1f);
            else
                checkBox.setAlpha(0f);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use onCheckedChangeListener

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
  if(isChecked) {
  buttonView.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE
```

}